# Python - MySql.Connector UPDATE statement not working

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I am having some problems with my UPDATE statement with MySQL.Connector.

My code apparently works sometimes and others not, and I don't understand why. 
I made a test function, for one row, which is very similar to my other main function.

```
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime

def connect(): 
    return mysql.connector.connect(host="xxxxx.xxx", user="xxx", passwd="xxxxxx", db="xxx")


def test():
    mydb = connect()
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT MAX(value) FROM test"
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    date = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    for x in mycursor.fetchall():
        updateSql = "UPDATE test SET date=%s WHERE value=%s"
        vals = (date, x[0])
        mycursor.execute(updateSql, vals)

        mydb.commit()
        print(vals)
        print(mycursor.rowcount)

test()
```

This code doesn't seem to be working, as the printed rowCount value is `0`.
My `vals` are correctly displayed : `('12-01-2020 16:47:15', 'testValue')`

However, what is shown on the database is : `'00-00-0000 00:00:00'` .
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What happens if you update with just the date value and not the string representation of the date? So remove the `.strftime()` part and do this: `date = datetime.now()`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: just found the answer.

I was using the wrong formatting. 
`date = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")` wasn't properly recognized.

The DATETIME type in mySql databases requires the format to be the following:

`date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

with the Year in the first place, Month in the second one, and Day in the third one.

If this standard isn't followed then the date will be converted into `0000:00:00 00:00:00` .